# Fail on .expect() but want to continue the test in TestCafe

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

```
t.expect(1).eql(2)
```

So Basically,on this [Site](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/400167/test-concepts/assertions),it tells that *If an assertion fails, the test fails too.*

So the code I post above will stop any testcase I'm running.

But I want to Still run the following code(sorry I don't have code on hand),is there anyway that can use?I now use a not-so-good way,that is

1. list down the check value to an array
2. after the list is complete,do the .expect()

but I think this is not good,because there will be lots of steps and I think maybe they can be reduce.

Thanks in advance if anyone got some helpful idea!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot continue a test after an incorrect `expect` with the TestCafe interface. I recommend you separate all checks into their own tests. If you have an array of values that you want to check, you can use `test` in a loop. For example:

```js
fixture('Fixture').page('./index.html');

const arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2];

for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    test(`Test ${index}`, async () => {
        await t.expect(arr[index]).eql(1);
    })
}
```

Each iteration has its own test. If you run it, you will see which of the tests are successful and which are not.

If this solution is not suitable for you, you can use the `try-catch` javascript syntax. However, in this case, you will just see which test is successful without any information about failed steps.

Comment: the ```test``` answer is a good one,which can shows me the true situation in every data I want to test.I want to know if I can reduce them into one case(I once try to use arrays to record the right value and wrong value,and use the .expect to trigger the error to make a report,that is what I want to do),but if I use the ```test loop``` answer,the report will be in a huge scale.I'm trying to figure this out.But thanks for the answer Aleksey!

Comment: The best practice is to not include everything in one test. That is why I recommend you separate it. The report will be huge, but it shows information about all data. However, you can include `expect` in `try...catch`. Then, tests won't be interrupted by any errors. Save errors from `catch` and throw them at the end of the test or use check count of errors with `expect`: `await the.expect(countErrors).eql(0)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the test immediately after an assertion failure, you can use the t.expect().eql() method instead of t.expect().ok(). This will throw an error and stop the test if the assertion fails.

```
test('My Test', async t => {
  await t
    .navigateTo('https://example.com')
    .expect(getPageTitle()).ok('Title is not as expected')
    .click('#myButton')
    .expect(getResultText()).ok('Result is not as expected');
});
```

In the above example, if the expect(getPageTitle()).ok() assertion fails, it will report the failure in the test results, but the test will continue to run and execute the remaining steps. Similarly, if the expect(getResultText()).ok() assertion fails, it will also report the failure in the test results but will continue to run the test.

If you want to stop the test immediately after an assertion failure, you can use the t.expect().eql() method instead of t.expect().ok(). This will throw an error and stop the test if the assertion fails.